# Where is /tmp/q debugging file on macOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, debugging

On macOS, when I execute this simple Python code using [q package](https://github.com/zestyping/q):

```
import q
q('test')
```

I have not the file `/tmp/q` created as my zsh session shows:

```
cat /tmp/q
cat: /tmp/q: No such file or directory
```

However the documentation states [here](https://github.com/zestyping/q#q):

> All output goes to /tmp/q (or on Windows, to $HOME/tmp/q)

Comment: Works fine for me. Does you shell have `$TMPDIR` pointing to a different directory?

Comment: I'm on macOS 13.6 ? Same for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for me was to set explicitly $TMPDIR:

```
export TMPDIR=/tmp
python3
>>> import q
>>> q('test')
'test'
>>> exit()
cat /tmp/q
 3.9s <module>: 'test'
```

I think the issue is specific only to macOS because `TMPDIR` is set to some subdir in `/var/folders/`:

```
printenv | grep TMPDIR
TMPDIR=/var/folders/xm/5_2mty4j0415dv2nqdct2twr0000gq/T/
```

Comment: The reason it worked for me is because I set `TMPDIR=/tmp` in my zsh environment _ages_ ago (and forgot about it) :D